# how to get SimpleDateFormat to give me numbers like 13/6/2021?

Tags: java, android-studio

is there a way to let the simple date format to give me numbers not names its giving me 12 jul, 2021

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
``
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` as shown, is doing nothing, please consider adding a [mcve] to question (with `sdf.format(new Date())` I get `06/13/2021`) ((but not on android))

Comment: Did you try `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: and, if you want `13/6/2021`, use the `dd/M/yyyy` format - hard to understand how posted format is resulting in `12 Jul, 2021`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for :

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;  // Import the LocalDateTime class
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  // Import the DateTimeFormatter class

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();  
    System.out.println("Before Formatting: " + myDateObj);  
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");  
    
    String formattedDate = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);  
    System.out.println("After Formatting: " + formattedDate);  
  }  
}  

// Output:

/*
Before Formatting: 2021-06-13T19:28:32.056915

After Formatting: 13/06/2021
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LocalDate from java.time, the modern Java date and time API

```java
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, u", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("June 27, 2007", dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Not sure whether this was what the asker had in mind. In any case your code gives us `2007-06-27`, so numbers and no names as asked.